# Button should work like scroll up and down

Tags: c#, windows

I have a windows application in which I have two buttons for moving the items up and down in the gridview.

`But the problem is:`

The click event is called only when I release the key.

`What I need:`

The click event should fire when I press and hold the key and should stop when I release the key. means something like scroll up and down button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MouseDown event of button change some class level member for instance

```
blnButtonPressed = ture;
```

On MouseUp event of button change

```
blnButtonPressed = false;
```

And do what ever you do between these two states....

Comment: Where should I perform the in between task..?

Comment: You can start a new thread for your task or you start background work for your task this my help you to understand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: My pleasure, you grabbed it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the click event.  Use the MouseDown and MouseUp events.

Or, if you want to deal with key presses, use the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom button, which will raise Click evens when its pressed. Here is simple way to do that:

```
public class PressableButton : Button
{
    private Timer _timer = new Timer() { Interval = 10 };

    public PressableButton()
    {
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        _timer.Stop();
    }      
}
```

After button was pressed, timer starts ticking every 10 ms (you can change interval). On timer tick event handler this button raises Clieck event.

To use it just compile project and drag PressedButton from ToolBox to your Form.